# how to specify test packge in `catkin_make test`

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

can we choose package to be tested? currently `catkin_make test` tests all test code under src directory, but I'd like to check only specific packages, in order to save time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/136951/how-to-specify-test-packge-in-%60catkin_make-test%60/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2014-03-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `test` target is CTest, you can read the CTest documentation if you want to use that target.

`catkin` provides the `run_tests` target which runs all the tests. You can tab complete `run_tests_` to get a target for each test you have registered which only runs that test.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2014-03-07**:
thank you, that is the perfect answer!

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2014-03-07**:
Another question, make run_tests_* exits with 0 even if the test failed. Is it expected behavior? is there a way to catch if the test failed?

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2014-03-07**:
thanks!, that works great.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, that is the expected behavior of any make target.

You can check the output / return code of the `catkin_test_results` script instead.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-03-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1